# Как в bootstrap выровнять sidebar в container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap5

Я хочу сделать чтобы sidebar был в container.

Сейчас получается что контент header идет в container, пытаюсь так же сделать и sidebar, но видно как вертикальная линия не соответствует header.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 48px 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .sidebar {
        top: 5rem;
    }
}

.sidebar-sticky {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 48px);
    padding-top: .5rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.sidebar .nav-link.active {
    color: rgba(88, 193, 234, 1);
}

.sidebar-heading {
    font-size: .75rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header .navbar-brand {
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
header a img {
    width: 160px;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler {
    top: .25rem;
    right: 1rem;
}

.bg-pss {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #22285A 0%, #417FE4 100%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>TEST</title>

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="navbar sticky-top bg-pss flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">

            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand col-md-3 col-lg-2 me-0 px-3" href="#"><img src="theme/images/logo.png"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute d-md-none collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebarMenu" aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <div class="nav-item text-nowrap">
                        <a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">Проверить заказ</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </header>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
                    <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
                        <ul class="nav flex-column">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active"href="#">Настройки</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Мои заказы</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Мой профиль</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">История баланса</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Выход</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3">
                        <h1 class="h2">Настройки</h1>
                    </div>
                </main>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. пожалуйста, запустите фрагмент кода на всю страницу чтобы увидеть неполадки.

Comment: Зачем он в контейнере, если Вы все равно на фикседе прижимаете его влево `left: 0` игнорируя по-сути марджин который дает контейнер? Таким образом и совпадать никогда не будет, так как там уже задана ширина `col-md-3 col-lg-2` как в шапке. Даже если уберете `left: 0` совпадать тоже не будет, так как в шапке Вы не используете `row`, хотя должны бы (так как колонка должна лежать внутри ряда `row`), сайдбар лежит внутри `row`, который дает дополнительный отступ, используйте тогда `row g-0`. Вам наверное стоит передалать лаяут другим образом.

Comment: Видимо Вы воспользовались [примером](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/dashboard/) но там сайдбар находится внутри `container-fluid`, а кнопка в `header` находится вне контейнера.